# Laravel 4.2 custom trait to encrypt data

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-4, traits

I tried to create a custom trait to encrypt the column 'email' of a model automatically:

```
<?php
trait EncryptData
{

public function getAttribute($key)
{
    $value = parent::getAttribute($key);

    if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable)) {
        $value = Crypt::decrypt($value);
    }
    return $value;
}

public function setAttribute($key, $value)
{
    if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable)) {
        $value = Crypt::encrypt($value);
    }

    return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
?>
```

I start my controller like this, which results in an exception    **Undefined property: MyModel::$encryptable**:

```
class MyModel extends BaseController{

Use EncryptData;
protected $encryptable = ['email'];
```

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: apparently, [you shouldn't do this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/74195)!

Comment: Yes I already suspected it is bad practice.
Any better ideas how to automatize the en- and decryption of certeain columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand correctly, this trait is used to encrypt model fields?

In this case, what I should do, is cread a `Model` class where each model extends from and add the functions in this class.

```
<?php

class Model {
    protected $encryptable;

    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        $value = parent::getAttribute($key);

        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable)) {
            $value = Crypt::decrypt($value);
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```

-

```
<?php

class User extends Model {
    function __construct(){
        $this->$encryptable = ['email'];
    }

}
```

Comment: That was the hint I needed.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the answer has helped you, consider marking it as the solution. ;)

Answer (score -3):

[here](https://github.com/esensi/model#manually-encrypting-model-attributes) is a package of nice traits.

- Validating Model Trait
- Purging Model Trait
- Hashing Model Trait
- Encrypting Model Trait
- Juggling Model Trait
- Soft Deleting Model Trait
- Relating Model Trait
- Sluggable Model Trait

This what You are looking for is `CryptingModelTrait`. I cant describe it better than docs say. Short note from docs:

This package includes the EncryptingModelTrait which implements the EncryptingModelInterface on any Eloquent model that uses it. The EncryptingModelTrait adds methods to Eloquent models for automatically encrypting attributes on the model whenever they are set and for automatically decrypting attributes on the model whenever they are got. The trait includes the ability to:

automatically encrypt attributes in the `$encryptable` property when setting them
automatically decrypt attributes in the `$encryptable` property when getting them
manually `encrypt/decrypt` a value using the `encrypt() and decrypt()` methods
check if a value is encrypted using the `isEncrypted()` method
swap out the encrypter class used using the `setEncrypter()` method
Like all the traits, it is self-contained and can be used individually. Be aware, however, that using this trait does overload the magic `__get()` and `__set()` methods of the model (see Esensi\Model\Model source code for how to deal with overloading conflicts).

Comment: Please provide more info. Don't just post link only answers.

Comment: @Jerodev. I wont give a ready answer, hint is more valuable. Just gave a package of solution this guy needs. There is good quality code and right solutions. Cant give more than ready working code, with best practices.

Comment: This is a reason I have quit this support community. Copy-paste developers judge others for their own ignorance